# It shows an error when executing the inheritance constructors "actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters, constructor, arguments

I have been doing some dummy executions and I tried to execute this but shows no argument error.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Adder{  
    int a;
    Adder(int a){
        this.a=a;
        System.out.println(a+"Base");
    }
}  
class ad extends Adder{
    int b;
    ad(int b){
        this.b=b;
        System.out.println(b+"Derivative");
    }
}
class TestOverloading1{  
public static void main(String[] args){  
ad obj = new ad(5);


}}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Main.java:17: error: constructor Adder in class Adder cannot be applied to given types;
    ad(int b){
             ^
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

What am i doing wrong here? I also tried using two arguments for the derivative class's constructor but also has the same error

Comment: you need to pass `a` to `Adder` using super(a) in the constructor

Comment: Add `super(b);` as the first line of the subclass constructor.